# CSS selector within style of another selector

Tags: css

I have seen the following before, but cannot find it on Google. I am wondering if it is a framework. Also, is this good practice?

```
body {
    position:absolute;
    p {
        float:left;
    }
}
```

Basically, there are some selectors nested within others. I don't know if I'mk Googling the wrong words, or if this is hard to find because it's a bad idea. So the question is: what is this nesting thing, and should/can I use it?

EDIT:

Is there a way that it could come out as:

```
body {
    position:absolute;
    p {
        float:left
    }
}
```

that would then compile to:

```
body {
    position:absolute;
}
body p {
    position:absolute; 
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is SCSS type of programming for CSS.

You need compiler later to compile to CSS code.

```
body {
    position:absolute;
    p {
        float:left;
    }
}
```

will be compiled to:

```
body {
    position:absolute; 
}
body p {
    float:left;
}
```

http://sass-lang.com/ for more informations.

Comment: Does the body p selector inherit position:absolute? (learning on my own here)

Comment: In css this isninvalid syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or `.scss` files, not CSS. It is a language that is [preprocessed](https://www.urbaninsight.com/2012/04/12/ten-reasons-you-should-be-using-css-preprocessor) to become CSS. It it good practise for readability, however it is not CSS. As it stands it will not work in a browser.

```
body {
    position:absolute;
    p {
        float:left;
    }
}
```

Is processed to become:

```
body { position:absolute; }
body p { float:left; }
```

### Edit

To make what you describe you would just do this:

```
body {
    position:absolute;
    p {
        position:absolute;
        float:left;
    }
}
```

Is processed to become:

```
body { position:absolute; }
body p { position:absolute; float:left; }
```

If you are interested on what happens to it when processed, you can have a look on Codepen by setting the CSS to be SCSS. I have setup what you are working with here:

http://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/zNjpLP

You can click "View compiled CSS" in the dropdown to see how it works.

[image]

Comment: You should be able to edit your question to add further code if you need to.